# SpringBoot's bootBuildImage with Kaniko instead of a Docker daemon

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kaniko

SpringBoot 2.3 introduced a feature to create OCI/Docker images by running `./gradlew bootBuildImage` instead of having a `Dockerfile` and execute `docker build .`

When building on a Gitlab build server that is running inside a Kubernetes cluster there is no Docker daemon available though (no docker-in-docker service for security reasons). Instead images have to be build and uploaded using Google's "Kaniko" tool.

Is it possible to combine both somehow i.e. use "bootBuildImage" without a running Docker daemon?

Comment: What do you mean by 'combine both'? You want to somehow use Kaniko instead of a local Docker Daemon?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or maybe, if SpringBoot creates a `Dockerfile` and then calls Docker, have it write the Dockerfile and then stop so that I can use Kaniko to actually build the Image.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#build-image-docker-daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using [Podman](https://podman.io/). Podman includes a daemon that implements a Docker-compatible API. On a local machine this can be started via `podman system service --time 0 tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`.

When running in Kubernetes (or generally in a container) you can use the container image from Quay: `quay.io/containers/podman`. Start the service in the background and the run your build. Something like this should work:

```yaml
build:
  image: my-java-builder
  services:
    - name: quay.io/containers/podman:v4.2.1
      alias: docker
      command: ["podman", "system", "service", "--time=0", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  script:
    - ./gradlew bootBuildImage
```

Comment: I get from this from the Podman service container: `mount /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay, flags: 0x1000: permission denied` (using GitLab's Kubernetes Executor). From what I understand it is [AppArmor](https://apparmor.net/) which is blocking this request. Unfortunately, AppArmor is common on some K8s clusters.

Answer (score -1):

Derkoe, should be: `command: ["podman", "system", "service", "--time=0", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]`

Besides, running the previous solution with Maven: `mvn spring-boot:build-image -e`, I got the error:

```
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny' 0%
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny' 0%
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:55c9883c40ff9f3a41e6db168266b7b21d04b5e63bbde99c9976f1d7458f7153'
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:tiny-cnb' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:11d6196c9185cbb5eff12410ebc14ad5a19edc6553329b5d3d2ae7a95ed723f9'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.16.0
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-1faddfe7a378.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to initialize docker client: failed to connect to docker socket: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: connection refused
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea?

Comment: Adding `<bindHostToBuilder>true</bindHostToBuilder>` according to [spring-boot-maven-plugin docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.docker.podman) fixes my problem